# Display specific fields from a row for duplicate values in a column

Tags: duplicate

i/p -

```
1234505403650,1234505403650,1,XYZ,0,,
1234525941210,1234525941210,1,XYZ,0,,
1234505577168,1234505577168,1,XYZ,0,,
1234518552859,1234518552859,1,XYZ,0,,
1234518552859,1234518552859,1,RTB,0,20200818153307,20200819153307
1234513321215,1234513321215,1,XYZ,0,,
1234523098739,1234523098739,1,XYZ,0,,
1234500964747,1234500964747,1,XYZ,0,,
1234500964747,1234500964747,1,ABC,0,,
```

expected o/p -

```
1234518552859,XYZ,RTB
1234500964747,XYZ,ABC
```

Need to identify duplicate entries from first field and display `<duplicate entry>,<field 4>` from all rows matching duplicate entry

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
    {a[$1] = a[$1] == "" ? $4 : a[$1]","$4; c[$1]++} 
    END {for(i in a){if (c[i]>1) print i,a[i]}}
' file
1234518552859,XYZ,RTB
1234500964747,XYZ,ABC
```